# CSS Media query: max-width rule not applied

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design, media-queries, screen-resolution

I have the below media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .class-something {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

The above rule doesn't get applied for resolution 800px width. If i give the max-width as 830px(anything above this), it gets applied.

I am using [web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) firefox plugin to check the app in different resolutions.

Why is it not applying the rule when i give the exact resolution? Is it a problem with the plugin i am using to test? Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: My assumption was that max-width was the same as saying <=  however after doing some testing I am getting the feeling that it is only <  http://jsbin.com/UHeqahE/1/

Comment: I would venture a bet that you have some other media query that is overiding this one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in firefox the toolbars width affects the viewport width.

Disable toolbars in firefox for testing, in my case I had to disable nav and bookmarks, but when enabled nav toolbar again (to type another url) the issue wasn't present and resizing the window works as expected.